# Is it possible to create an executable jar using pack200?

Tags: java, jar

An application I am developing has an executable jar of about 7MB. When I archive it using the pack200 tool, the size of the tar.gz file is just 2MB.

Is there a way to make this .tar.gz file executable (without using JNLP)? That is, users should be able to launch the application with a simple command such as: `java -jar xyz.jar` or `java -jar xyz.tar.gz`

After searching for a long time about pack200, I am only able to find information in the context of JNLP.

Answer (score 1):

It should work when the `gz` option is **NOT** used, jar file created by the following command should work fine with `java -jar`:

```
pack200 -r -G compressed.jar uncompressed.jar
```

But the `.gz` file created by the following command may not work with `java -jar`:

```
pack200 compressed.jar.gz uncompressed.jar
```

`-r` is to repack the jar and `-G` is to strip debug information. They do give some compression but not as much as the `gz` option gives.

If you have to use .gz option to reduce the size for reasons including making your jar available for download, then the client (who downloads your jar) can unpack and use it, Eclipse update for example works that way!

More about pack200 [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/pack200.html)

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Do you have any idea why this is so? Is it because gzip is not suitable for decompression on the fly?

Comment: I don't see why it should not be possible, at least theoretically!! unpack200 can unpack the gzip behind the scene...